# How to have images in a JavaScript quiz?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a basic JavaScript quiz for my younger anime-loving siblings. I want to be able to have a different picture available for each question. How and Where could insert images for the questions? Notes about the quiz only one question are shown at a time. For the sake of publishing, I took out all the questions, aside from the first one.
Code below:

```
var pos = 0,
  test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, chD, correct = 0;

var questions = [{ //1
    question: "What is Dazai's power from Bungo Stray Dogs?",
    a: "No Longer Human",
    b: "For the Tainted Sorrow",
    c: "Rashomon",
    d: "Unbreakable",
    answer: "A"
  }
];

function get(x) {
  return document.getElementById(x);
}

function renderQuestion() {
  test = get("test");
  if (pos >= questions.length) {
    test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got " + correct + " of " + questions.length + " questions correct</h2>";
    get("test_status").innerHTML = "Test completed";

    pos = 0;
    correct = 0;

    return false;
  }
  get("test_status").innerHTML = "Question " + (pos + 1) + " of " + questions.length;

  question = questions[pos].question;
  chA = questions[pos].a;
  chB = questions[pos].b;
  chC = questions[pos].c;
  chD = questions[pos].d;

  test.innerHTML = "<h3>" + question + "</h3>";


  test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> " + chA + "</label><be>";
  test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> " + chB + "</label><be>";
  test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> " + chC + "</label><be>";
  test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='D'> " + chD + "</label><br><be>";
  test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
}

function checkAnswer() {

  choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
  for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    if (choices[i].checked) {
      choice = choices[i].value;
    }
  }

  if (choice == questions[pos].answer) {
    correct++;
  }
  pos++;

  renderQuestion();
}

window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion);
```

Comment: @LawrenceCherone vue wasn't tagged and is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: lets all go back to the stone age, no point making cars, when we can just walk

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your HTML to replicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's relatively simple, you're already creating other DOM elements by concatenating them to the end of an element's `innerHTML`; what you're looking to do is no different.

Just add another property to your question objects, and add the respective [`<img>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) where desired in your concatenation statements:

```js
var pos = 0,
  test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, chD, correct = 0;

var questions = [{ //1
    question: "What is Dazai's power from Bungo Stray Dogs?",
    a: "No Longer Human",
    b: "For the Tainted Sorrow",
    c: "Rashomon",
    d: "Unbreakable",
    answer: "A",
    //Add property to hold image source uri, either local or online
    img: "https://blog.qwant.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2016/01/test.jpg"
  }];

function get(x) {
  return document.getElementById(x);
}

function renderQuestion() {
  test = get("test");
  if (pos >= questions.length) {
    test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got " + correct + " of " + questions.length + " questions correct</h2>";
    get("test_status").innerHTML = "Test completed";

    pos = 0;
    correct = 0;

    return false;
  }
  get("test_status").innerHTML = "Question " + (pos + 1) + " of " + questions.length;

  question = questions[pos].question;
  chA = questions[pos].a;
  chB = questions[pos].b;
  chC = questions[pos].c;
  chD = questions[pos].d;
  //Add local var to hold uri
  img = questions[pos].img;

  test.innerHTML = "<h3>" + question + "</h3>";
  
  //Add <img> element to DOM with source
  test.innerHTML += "<img src=\"" + img + "\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\"><br>";

  test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> " + chA + "</label><be>";
  test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> " + chB + "</label><be>";
  test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> " + chC + "</label><be>";
  test.innerHTML += "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='D'> " + chD + "</label><br><be>";
  test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
}

function checkAnswer() {
  choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
  for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
    if (choices[i].checked) {
      choice = choices[i].value;
    }
  }

  if (choice == questions[pos].answer) {
    correct++;
  }

  pos++;

  renderQuestion();
}

window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion);
```

```html
<div id="test_status"></div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

If you're feeling fancy, you could even add a width and height property to your question objects with the url to add dynamically to the `<img>` tag.

---

As an aside, you may very well benefit from looking into a [templating library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_templating) for projects like this, even small ones. Libraries like [Vue](http://vuejs.org/) make things much easier, and cleaner, than concatenating to the `innerHTML` of a DOM element.

Comment: Thanks this works really well, I appreciate this. I will look into templating libraries as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your questions collection, just add a `url` attribute that contains the urls of the images you uploaded somewhere, either online, or locally, using unix notation.

ex: `url: "./images/question1.jpg"`

then

`test.innerHTML += "<img src=" + questions[index].url + " />;"` to add it to the DOM. (Index is the index of the collection item you want to render, probably using that for loop you have or a map function.)